# The instance of entity type cannot be tracked on saving data to multiple table

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-core, blazor-server-side

Here I am trying to save the person detail in `Person` table and person related file to `PersonFileUpload` table on single submit.
But on submit it shows error saying `'The instance of entity type 'PersonFileUpload' cannot be tracked because another instance with the same key value for {'FileId'} is already being tracked.`  in line `uow.Repository<Person>().Add(person);`.
Below is my code and Table structure

```
 public Person PersonModel { get; set; } = new Person();
    IReadOnlyList<IBrowserFile> selectedFiles;
    public void postPerson()
    {
        List<PersonFileUpload> fileList = new List<PersonFileUpload>();
        foreach (var file in selectedFiles)
        {               
            fileList.Add(new PersonFileUpload() { UploadedFileName = file.Name });
            
        }
        PersonModel.PersonFileUpload = fileList;
        mainService.SavePerson(PersonModel);           
    }
```

```
public void SavePerson(Person person)
    {
        if (person.PersonId == 0)
        {
            uow.Repository<Person>().Add(person);
            uow.Commit();
        }
        else
        {
            uow.Repository<Person>().Edit(person);
            uow.Commit();
        }
    }
```

Person Table

```
public partial class Person
{
    public Person()
    {
        PersonFileUpload = new HashSet<PersonFileUpload>();
    }

    public int PersonId { get; set; }
    public string FullName { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public string Address { get; set; }
    public int? CountryId { get; set; }
    public int? CityId { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<PersonFileUpload> PersonFileUpload { get; set; }
}
```

PersonFileUpload table

```
public partial class PersonFileUpload
{
    public int FileId { get; set; }
    public int? PersonId { get; set; }
    public string UploadedFileName { get; set; }
    public virtual Person Person { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: why do you have 2 different `PersonFileUpload` objects with the same `FileId` value? it seems that you have 1 object that you retrieved from the database and 1 object that you created in the code.If this is a foreign key relationship, then you would need to get the original object from data base. Or make sure that the  `FileId` value does not already exist if you want to insert an entirely new  `PersonFileUpload` objects

Answer (score 0):

There can be multiple reasons/places in your code that cause this. In the nutshell, you have multiple instances of PersonFileUpload tracked by your db context, of which is one instance probably when you fetched those objects and other one when you tried to save them. There are few reasons that came to mind right away but without more code from you, can't be sure which is it. Since it seems that you are using Unit of Work apparently, I am guessing that you are fetching PersonFileUpload files which remain tracked by your context before you call Add for your person.

You can try to do next when you fetch your PersonFileUpload entities:

Try to use AsNoTracking:

```
var fileUploads = dbContext.PersonFileUploads.AsNoTracking().Where(...).ToList();
```

Or you can use Detach for PersonFileUpload entities:

```
dbContext.Entry(fileUploadEntity).State = EntityState.Detached
```